# Pivot Point Question

Tags: modeling, origin, 3d-cursor, proportional-editing

Been wondering how to do this for ages but I haven't been able to find a solution, or phrase a search correctly, please link if it's out there.

Here's two abstract flower petals, I want to pivot them towards each other by selecting both and pivoting them in relation to one point, either origin point of each petal or the 3d cursor.

[image]

With four petals:

[image]

With multiple petals:

[image]

I tried: <kbd>TAB</kbd> Edit mode, Select top vertex of each petal, <kbd>O</kbd> turn on proportional edit, <kbd>G</kbd>, Increase Proportional Scale with wheel and move up and down. But this is imprecise and warps the object slightly, with a more complex organic 'petal' problems start arising.

[image]

How would you do this?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can change your pivot point to 3D cursor and then select all verts and rotate without proportional editing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The main trick is to use the *Local* transform orientation, since you want all objects to rotate according to their own individual axes. In the video below I'm using the *3D Cursor* as the pivot point, because the origin points of my petals are in their geometric centers and not at the pivot point I want them to rotate from (here, that's also the world origin).

[image]

If their object origins were at the world center so everything was perfectly symmetrical, all other pivot options would yield the same result:

[image]

Comment: A perfectly elegant solution, thank you.